# convolution of Schwartz functions with $f(x) = (1+\|x\|)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, differential-operators

Let $f(x) = (1+\|x\|)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This is clear that $f\star g \notin \mathcal S$ where $\mathcal S$ is algebra of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $ g \in \mathcal S$. My question:
does $f\star g$ belong to Schatten ideal  $ S^ {P}$ for some $p$?

Comment: The convolution could be in $\mathcal{S}$, but it depends on $g$. For example take a $g$ with $\widehat{g}=0$ in a neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: I mean in general.